# Java Iterator Interface remove() method. how it will work and produce expected result

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator, time-complexity

I wondered how this Iterator remove() work

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1); list.add(2); list.add(3); list.add(4);

Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    int x = it.next();
    if(x%2==0) it.remove();
    else System.out.println(x+" ");
}
 o/p : 1 3
```

How this method work? If remove() any element.it remove from array and shift to right? I try other option remove(index) or remove(object) method present in collection it lead to exception any Java experts pls explain and mention the Time Complexity of this method remove() present in Iterator interface

Comment: This is more about bugs in your code that uses other approaches to remove than anything else -- but we can't really explain those unless you show us that code, so we can identify the exact bugs.

Comment: Really "left" and "right" have no meaning in an array. It shifts towards index 0. I suspect most people (English speakers at least) would picture index 0 being the left-most, in which case it's shifting *left*. Time complexity is O(n^2). N iterations over the collection, and each remove takes N operations to shift everything. In a LinkedList, it would be O(n), because remove just involves setting a couple of pointers and is constant time

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` class has a class called `Itr`. The `Itr` implements `remove()` method of `Iterator` interface like this:

```
public void remove() {
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
            cursor = lastRet;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
```

in there:

- `lastRet` - last returned index of elements' array from `next()`
- `cursor` - current element's index

Comment: Really helpful now understand the working flow